IR pulse sensor : signal stops after a few pulses
I'm trying to make a pulse sensor based on this tutorial: https://makezine.com/projects/ir-pulse-sensor/.
I therefore reproduced this diagram by replacing the LM354s with MCP6002s and without amplifying the signal with the transistor (I recovered the signal at the output of the last OA with an oscilloscope).


I used tantalum capacitors for the polarized capacitors and ceramic capacitors for the others.
The circuit seems to work for a few seconds but the voltage drops and only rises again after removing the finger from the sensor.

I don't understand this behavior and I don't know if it corresponds to a capacitor discharge problem or a problem with the OAs. I thank you in advance for your help.

There should be a feedback resistor of around 1 Mohm in parallel with the 100 nF capacitor on the left op-amp.

Thanck you very much !

Some schematic details might mislead others.
The infrared diode emitter and infrared detector were described as RS 276-142 (a discontinued item). The emitter is indeed a diode, and schematic shows it properly biased.
The problem is with detector. Schematic shows it as a photodiode. This is likely incorrect. It is described by others as a phototransistor. The infrared emitter is usually encased in a dark-coloured resin, while the phototransistor is encased in clear resin.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
 A red LED can detect light similarly to a photodiode. It creates small photocurrents that can be detected by an op amp. Photocurrents are significantly smaller than the phototransistor's collector current of Q1 shown above. A large-value resistor (R7) can help boost gain.

It is possible that OP's substitution of CMOS opamp for the bipolar LM324 requires additional components to work properly, as Andy has suggested. Input bias current differ significantly between MCP6002 and LM324.
